# Name of a generalized version of semi-continuity

Tags: real-analysis

I have recently made use of the following generalization of a continuous function, which seems simple enough it ought to have been used before, but I cannot find any references.

We will say a function $f$ has a semi-continuity property if $f^{-1}(U)$ contains a non-empty open set whenever $U$ is a non-empty open set.

Is this a studied property?  If $f:X\to Y$ and $Y$ is disconnected, then this disagrees with usual continuity but does provide some nice properties.  For instance, if $D$ is a dense set, then $f(D)$ is dense.

Comment: The empty set is open. Do you mean $f^{-1}U$ contains a *non-empty* open set whenever $U$ is a *non-empty* open set?

Comment: I do. The question has been corrected.

Comment: I wouldn't call this "semi-continuity", since upper and lower semi-continuity have nothing to do with this.

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, can you give more interesting properties of this generalization? Thanks :)

Comment: Here's a note: A sufficient condition for $f : X \to Y$ to have this property is that there is an open set $U \subset X$ such that $f$ is continuous on $U$, and $f(U) = f(X)$.  If so, then on $X \setminus U$, $f$ can be as discontinuous as it likes.

Comment: @Shamisen The property that I have used is if $(X,T)$ and $(Y,S)$ are dynamical systems with $f\circ T = S\circ f$ and $f$ is onto, then if $f$ has this property, $(X,T)$ minimal implies $(Y,T)$ is minimal.  Though this follows quickly from the density property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This property has been studied and it goes by the name [**somewhat continuous**](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22somewhat+continuous%22+topology).

FYI, I was led to this discovery by its mention in the middle of p. 92 of Zbigniew Piotrowski's 1987 survey paper [*A survey of results concerning generalized continuity on topological spaces*](http://web.ysu.edu/gen/stem_generated_bin/documents/basic_module/A_survey_of_results_concerning_generalized_continuity_on_topological_spaces.pdf), and the google search I give above confirmed that this property has been studied a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's been studied, but here's an example to show how pathological functions with your property can be.  Take $X = Y = (0,1)$.  Enumerate the
nonempty open intervals in $Y$ with rational endpoints as $I_n$, $n \in \mathbb N$. The only constraints we put on $f$ are that $f([1/(n+1),1/n)) \subseteq I_n$.  Then $f$ satisfies your property.